# Making 2 dimensoinal array from csv

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv

here is my csv,

```
Nejvíce za měsíc;;
1.;Jack;900
2.;George;850
3.;Martin;800
4.;John;700
5.;Martin;701
```

In my code I loading it from dropbox

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/11ofmbg4d4y3gb0/Top.csv',
  dataType: 'text',
}).done(successFunction);
```

My code creates only 1 dimensional array.

```
function successFunction(data) {

  var promenna = data.split(";");
  console.log(promenna);

}
```

I would like to create array from it and it should like this. How can I do that?

```
var promenna = [
  ["Nejvíce za měsíc", "900"],
  ["Jack", "900"],
  ["George", "850"],
  ["Martin", "800"],
  ["John", "700"],
  ["Martin", "701"],
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this :

```
var data = "1.;Jack;900\n" + 
           "2.;George;850\n" +
           "3.;Martin;800";

var promenna = data.replace(/\n/g,";").split(";");
var result = [];
console.log(promenna);
for(var i = 0; i < promenna.length; i+=3) {
    var line = [];
    line.push(promenna[i+1]);
    line.push(promenna[i+2]);
    result.push(line);
}

console.log(result);
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3t26cr8v/)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted. But i cant find what if I have different data. What if i would like to create 5 dimensional layer and what if 2?

Comment: @Ostrov Not sure I understood what you want, but if you want to have an similar array but with like 5 entries instead of 2, just change the `i+=3` to `i+=<number of entry in your line>`, then push what you want in the line. `[i]` is the first entry ("1.","2.",...), `[i+1]` the second ("Jack","George"), etc...

Comment: Lets say that I would create  from toAray aray see the codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VKXNvO

Comment: @Ostrov yup, as I said change i+=3 to i+=4 (since you have 4 entries per line) and then use line.push(promenna[i]), line.push([i+1])... [i+2], [i+3]

Comment: Thanks! I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

Little correction in your code and its working. You can try it in your browser console;

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/11ofmbg4d4y3gb0/Top.csv',
    dataType: 'text',
}).done(successFunction);

function successFunction(data) {
    var promenna = data.split(";"),
        tempArr = [],
        len = promenna.length;
    for (let i = 0; i <= len; i += 2) {
        tempArr.push([promenna[i], promenna[i+1]]);
    }
    console.log(tempArr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DEclare an array first then push your results into that array

function successFunction(data) {

```
        var finalArray = new Array();
        var promenna = data.split(";");
        finalArray.push(promenna);
        console.log(finalArray);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Join via with `splice` on the resulting array.

```js
var arr = [
  'Nejvíce za měsíc',
  '',
  'Jack',
  900,
  'George',
  850,
  'Martin',
  800,
  'John',
  700,
  'Martin',
  701
];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i] = [arr[i], arr.splice(i + 1, 1).pop()];
}
console.log(arr)
```